# Wait on multiple dialog inputs before processing data using Runnables

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, dialog

I thought I'd figured out this problem, by making a function `showMessage`, which can take a `Runnable` as an argument and run that piece of code if that particular button has been pressed.

Now I find the problem that I need to wait on several inputs before running the code. I essentially go through a bunch of questions which are added dynamically, so I don't know how many there'll be. When the users presses "Submit", it checks if any that are "soft" required and if there's no answer pops up with the message "There isn't an answer, would you like to continue anyway?".

The way I thought I could handle this is by counting the amount of questions which are like that, assigning them an Enumerator with a boolean variable to say if they're `INPROGRESS` or `COMPLETE`. I then had the `Runnable` to set that particular question's `Progress state` to `COMPLETE` and if they click "No", then to set the boolean variable to `false`.

Since the the dialogs are launched asynchronously, I can't just do an if statement, so I did a while any were still in progress. Buuuuuut! When I click submit now, it just freezes. I'm guessing because it's stuck at the while loop, whilst also not launching the dialogs asynchronously. I think it has to "complete" the code before launching them?

My code for reference to the points made above, this is all in the `onClick` of the submit button:

```
//Prep work
            final ArrayList<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();
            for (BaseQuestion q : questionViews)
            {
                if (q.requiredSoft)
                {
                    results.add(Result.INPROGRESS);
                }
            }
            final int[] i = {0};
            //Validation checks
            Boolean allOk = true;
            for (BaseQuestion questionView : questionViews)
            {
                if (questionView.isRequiredHard())
                {
                    if (questionView.getResponse().isEmpty())
                    {
                        Utils.showMessage("You have to fill in '" + questionView.getQuestionText() + "'", v.getContext());
                        allOk = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if (questionView.isRequiredSoft())
                {
                    if (questionView.getResponse().isEmpty())
                    {
                        Runnable isOk = new Runnable() 
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                results.get(i[0]).value = 1;
                                results.get(i[0]).result = true;
                                i[0]++;
                            }
                        };
                        Runnable isNotOk = new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                results.get(i[0]).value = 1;
                                i[0]++;
                            }
                        };
                        Utils.showMessage("You've not filled in '" + questionView.getQuestionText() + "'. Do you wish to continue?", v.getContext() , isOk, "Yes", isNotOk,  "No"); 
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            if (allOk)
            {
                for (Result result : results)
                {
                    while (result == Result.INPROGRESS) 
                    {
                    }
                    if (!result.result)
                    {
                        allOk = false;
                    }
                }
                if (allOk)
                {
                    submitQuestionnaire();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put all soft check into a runnable link， and do the submit action at the last runnable. I not have a IDE now, see following logic

```
on submit button clicked{
    allOk = true;
    foreach(question in questions){
        if(question require hard && question is empty){
            allOk = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(allOk){
        boolean needMoreConfirm = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
            if(question require soft && question is empty){
                 Runnable isOk = new MyRunnable(i + 1, questions);/*begin check from next question*/
                 Utils.showMessage("your question", 
                       new MyRunnable(i + 1)/* check next soft */, 
                       null/*do nothing, wait another submit click*/);
                 needMoreConfirm  = true;
                 break;
            }
        }
        if(!needMoreConfirm){
            do real submit here
        }
    }
}

class MyRunnable extends Runnable{
    protected int mIdx;
    Question[] mQuestions;
    public MyOkRunnalbe(int idx, Question[] qs){mIdx = idx; mQuestions = qs;}
    public void run(){
        boolean needMoreConfirm = false;
        for(int i = mIdx; i < questions.length; i++){
            if(mQuestions[i] is empty && mQuestions[i] is soft){
                Utils.showMessage("your question", 
                       new MyRunnable(i + 1)/* begin to check from next soft */, 
                       null/*do nothing, wait another submit click*/);
                needMoreCOnfirm = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!needMoreConfirm){
            do real submit here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get your approach, does it check each question i times? Can you explain it a bit more succinctly, please? Thanks!

Comment: it check each question one time. "new MyRunnable(i + 1, questions);"  and "for(int i = mIdx; i < questions.length; i++)" will make sure that we check each question one time.

Comment: It's ok! I solved it! I'll post my answer in a second.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

If I gave myself another half an hour to tinker, would've been fine! I whacked the checking code in a separate thread, this means it wasn't hanging.

But then I had the problem of the result not changing state. So instead of doing my for loop as a `for each item` loop, I did it as an index, as it wasn't changing the state when it kept checking.

As shown below:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (allOk[0])
                    {
                        for (int i=0; i<results.size(); i++)
                        {
                            while (results.get(i) == Result.INPROGRESS) 
                            {
                            }
                            if (!results.get(i).result)
                            {
                                allOk[0] = false;
                            }
                        }
                        if (allOk[0])
                        {
                            submitQuestionnaire();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
```